# Quantification and the existence of a function

Tags: elementary-set-theory, first-order-logic

I am trying hard to understand what exactly the axiom of choice (AC) is. I think much of the confusion comes from taking AC obvious not knowing what exactly ZF implies.

AC for nonempty indexed families $(B_x )_{x \in A}$ is represented by
$$
\forall x \in A:B_x \neq \varnothing \Rightarrow \exists f \in A \to \cup_{x \in A}B_x:\forall x \in A: f(x) \in B_x
$$
where $X \to Y$ denote the set of all functions from $X$ to $Y$.

For example, for sets $X$ and $Y$, and a predicate $P$, the statement
$$
\forall x \in X: \exists y \in Y: P(x,y)
\Rightarrow
\exists f \in X \to Y: \forall x \in X: P(x,f(x))
$$
is a direct consequence of AC as we can define $B_x = \{y \in Y|P(x,y)\}$. My question is, does the statement really need AC in ZF?

Comment: Yes. If AC is false in a model of set theory, then there's a family $(B_x)$ of nonempty sets without choice function. Define $Y:=\bigcup_x B_x$ and $P(x,y)=y\in B_x$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, AC is necessary for your statement because you can also prove AC from your statement in ZF:

To see this, assume your statement
$$
\forall x \in X: \exists y \in Y: P(x,y)
\Rightarrow
\exists f \in X \to Y: \forall x \in X: P(x,f(x)) \quad \cdots (\star)
$$

Next, assume the hypotheses of AC. That is, let $(B_x)_{x \in A}$ be an indexed family and suppose for all $x \in A$, we have $B_x \neq \varnothing$. So let $x \in A$. Since $B_x \neq \varnothing$ and $B_x \subseteq \bigcup_{x \in A} B_x$, the condition $\exists y \in \bigcup_{x \in A} B_x : y \in B_x$ is satisfied. Hence, by setting

- $X := A$
- $Y := \bigcup_{x \in A} B_x$
- $P(x, y) := y \in B_x$

In your statement $(\star)$, we get the conclusion that there exists some $f \in X \to Y$ i.e. $f \in A \to \bigcup_{x \in A} B_x$ such that for all $x \in X$ i.e. $x \in A$, we have $P(x, f(x))$ i.e. $f(x) \in B_x$.

This is exactly the conclusion you need for AC.

Comment: Ah... they are equivalent lol. Thank you!

Comment: @Hermis14 glad to be of help

Comment: btw, they don't seem to be a first-order equivalence because $P$ is quantified?

Comment: @Hermis14  $P$ is not quantified. Your statement is a theorem *schema*: for every formula $P(x, y)$, the statement is provable in ZFC. In extensions of ZF that allow quantification over classes (such as [NBG](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Von_Neumann%E2%80%93Bernays%E2%80%93G%C3%B6del_set_theory), or [KM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Morse%E2%80%93Kelley_set_theory)), you can quantify over $P$ to get a single sentence -- one that's still equivalent to AC. Note that NBG and KM are first-order theories, not higher-order.

Comment: @BrianO Wow, that is a really helpful comment for me. So, is it OK to conclude that I don't need a quantification over $P$ because there is one proposition for each $P$?

Comment: @Hermis14 Yes, one sentence for each formula $P$, each of them a theorem of ZFC. The quantification over formulas is *not* part of the ZFC theorem!, it's something we say "in the metatheory". The Comprehension and Replacement axioms of ZF(C) are schemas in the very same way, and similarly the various forms of the [Reflection Principle in ZFC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reflection_principle#In_ZFC).